# How to change color of primefaces tab inside tabView with orientation left?

Tags: primefaces

I use primefaces 5.2. I have a tabView with orientation as left. I need to change the color of the tab which is selected.

Here is my code:

```
<p:tabView orientation="left" id="tabViewID" dynamic="true"
                        cache="false"
                        activeIndex="#{manageBean.activeIndex}"
                        style="margin-left: 1%;width: 98%;background-color: #F5F5F5;">
                        <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                            listener="#{manageBean.fetchReports}" />
                        <p:tab title="Tab1" id="tabID1"  >

                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab title="Tab2">

                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab title="Tab3">

                        </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Any Idea??

Comment: @Geinmachi : By default the selected tab will be different from others right?? This is also not happening..

Comment: Is the problem still present when you remove `background-color: #F5F5F5;`?

Comment: I think you got some css style which overrides the PrimeFaces default one, try adding this style and tell if the selected tab color is red. `div ul li.ui-tabs-selected {
                background-color: red !important;
                background-image: none !important;
            }`

Comment: Entire background has become red. But the tabs still same.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect on Tab and to change color within default CSS Class..

try like this...

```
<style type="text/css">
        body .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-top .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active,
        body .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active,
        body .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-left .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active, 
        body .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active{
            background: #e4a1c2;
        }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces, tabs are rendered as a link (`<a>`) inside a list item (`<li>`).

I had a case where I wanted to change only the color of a specific tab.  This is how I did it :

1)  In the `<p:tab>` definition, I added a `titleStyleClass` to add a class definition to the list item (tab item) based on my condition :

```
<p:tab id="tab_id" title="#{campeur.prenomNom}" 
    titleStyleClass="#{campeur.nouveauCampeur ? 'tabNouveau' : 'tabExistant'}">
```

2) I added the style definition in my css to change the background color of the tab.  The color is ligther when the tab is not selected and is darker when the tab is selected or hovered over.  I applied this color change only when the class  `tabNouveau` was present, that is when my condition was met.  Otherwise, no particular styling for the `tabExistant` class :

```
li.tabNouveau a {
    background-color: #FFE289;
}

li.tabNouveau.ui-state-active a, li.tabNouveau.ui-state-hover a {
    background-color: #FFD44F;
 }
```

which gave the following result  :

[image]

Hope this can help others!